# with out reloading the total content when I click on the menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC with razor.
 In my application,I have a main menu in the layout page.
 In each Page,i have given this layout page to display menu in each page like,

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";  
  }
```

With this,When I select an item in the menu the total page is reloading,
what i want is when I select item in the menu,the content will only change with out disturbing the menu.can u tell me how to do this?
I have defined menu like

```
<div id="menu" style="width:80%;"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
            dataSource: [
                {
                    text: Home, 
                    encoded: false,
                    url:'@Url.Action("Index","Home")'

                },
                {
                       text: "<a href='@Url.Action("About","Home")'>About</a>",
                       encoded: false,
                }]
</script>
```

Comment: you can add iframes inside your page and load the page into it.. in this way the layout page will not be reloaded every time you press a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Ajax UI to accomplish this. The menu you're showing is rendering anchor tags which will indeed cause full page loads.

One other option is to come up with a scheme to maintain the state of the menu across page loads (i.e. make the nav points be controlled by rendered pages)